# Google Play, скачать apk пакеты на компьютер

Tags: android

Есть ли способ скачать пакеты из андроид маркета на компьютер? Я читал про установку маркета в виртуальную машину, но так и не смог этого сделать. Телефон у меня не рутованный, поэтому изнутри тоже вроде не получается добраться до пакетов. Узнал сегодня про Real APK Leecher, но и он работать отказывается.

Есть еще способы получить apk пакет из маркета? Может у кого есть описание протокола обмена между устройством с андроидом и маркетом?

Comment: Официально это сделать нельзя. И понятно почему. Протокол обмена народ вскрывает. На хабре была статья.

Comment: Скачать с маркета приложение и с устройства вытащить `apk`.

Comment: @monomi, для этого же нужно рутованное устройство? а у меня такого нет.

Comment: [тут](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=935754&d=1331126820) лежит АПК файл андроид маркета.

Comment: Приложение Маркет немного сложнее, чем кажется на первый взгляд. Там ещё как минимум один дополнительный сервис, который помогает GTalk, Push (GMS теперь) и разным внутренним фичам (проверка обновления к примеру).

Comment: @metalurgus, это для какого андроида? у меня на эмуляторе 8 и 16 андроида программа почти сразу же закрывается.

Comment: @mikelsv нет, рутованное не нужно. поставь на устройство какой-нибудь файловый менеджер (`ES Manager` или `ASTRO File Manager`) и забекапь нужное приложение. в итоге на `sd` будет лежать готовая `apk`.

Comment: [Как скачать APK с Google Play](http://101android.ru/kak-skachat-apk-s-google-play/) (из ответа, удалённого как ответ-ссылка).

Answer (score 1):

Может быть чем-то поможет это: [Download APK from Google Play The Easiest Way](http://geniusgeeks.com/download-apk-from-google-play-pc/)